# TFLearn - Quick Start results not matching

Tags: tensorflow

I looked at the [Tensorflow quick start guide](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples) but the results I am getting are not consistent with that of the ones posted. It is expected to predict `Winslet Surviving Rate` as 92% but I do not get that accuracy.

```
DiCaprio Surviving Rate: 0.15089160203933716
Winslet Surviving Rate: 0.624813973903656
```

And every subsequent run the prediction percentage is varying. Like it went down to almost 26%

```
DiCaprio Surviving Rate: 0.12503206729888916
Winslet Surviving Rate: 0.26697319746017456
```

Why are the results different?

Comment: Titanic dataset is somewhat proverbial in the ML community in that while you can train a model on it, it is not really meaningful and so any predictions it can make are not meaningful either. Besides, there is not nearly enough data in it to make the predictions consistent and accurate. So yes, relatively speaking, your model picked up that first class female has better survival chance than a third class male, but actual numbers vary widely.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1. How Much data is enough to make predictions? 2. What are the factors that might cause the Survival Rate fluctuations w/o any change in Code or Data - run on the same m/c multiple times.

Comment: First question is too general. But in case of Titanic dataset, you are trying to learn some complex relationships and you only have a bit over 2000 samples.

As for the second question, I am not sure if tflearn shuffles the data during training, but at the very least, the docs tell me that weights for the dense layers are picked randomly from a normal distribution. So your weights are going to start the training in a different place every time. You can try to modify the code slightly, set the weights initializer to all zeros and explicitly set shuffling to False and see things get consistent